# angularjs springmvc fileupload

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to angularjs and i am not able to understand the examples on internet for angularjs file upload directive. 
I have a following class :

```
@Entity
public class StudentPicture implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id private String studentId;
private byte[] picture;
// getters setters
}
```

And i want to save the picture in database
So far i have done this 
Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sampletest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void mySample(@RequestBody StudentPicture studentPicture) {

    System.out.println(studentPicture.getStudentId());
}
```

My jsp form is

```
var sample = angular.module('sample', [ "xeditable", "ui.bootstrap" ])
.config(function($httpProvider) {       
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] =    'XMLHttpRequest';
});
sample.controller("sampleController", function($scope, $http, $timeout, $filter) {
    $scope.studentId = "";
    $scope.picture = {};        
    $scope.uploadFile = function() {            
        var data = {studentId : $scope.studentId, picture: $scope.picture };            
        var response = $http.post('${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/sampletest', data);
        response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("jj");
        });
        response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({ data : data }));
        });
    };
});
</script>
<body>
<div ng-app="sample" ng-controller="sampleController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="studentId">
    <input type="file" ng-model="picture">
    <button ng-click="uploadFile">Submit</button>
</div>
```

My Multipart configuration is :

```
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000000);
    return multipartResolver;

}

@Bean
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement(){
    return new MultipartConfigElement("");

}
```

ERROR :
The request sent by client is syntactically incorrect

Comment: There is no file upload directive in your example. Uploading files with AJAX is a bit more complex and doesn't work with IE < 10. Since you are a beginner I strongly suggest to use an existing solution.

Comment: hello sir, i did searched for solutions but they are complex. can u please suggest or give link to some simple solutions. Just need to upload an image through ajax post method.

Comment: What about [this one](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Introduction#usage)? Looks quite simple. Just try any one and if you encounter a problem you can ask a new question.

Comment: Try to make it work with plain HTML to the server first. Then try to make Angular work. Use Chrome Developer tools and verify your HTTP traffic and JavaScript console.